# JPA, Execute Stored procedure in another database

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 databases,
the first one is main DB, and my PU configured to connect to this database
the 2nd database is used for other project but we use it because it has the employees and departments table and some generic stored procedures
I need to execute a stored procedure from the 2nd database

I tried  a lot to use

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("[otherDb].[dbo.][sp_name]");
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
query.getOutputParameterValue(1);
```

but always get exception:
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The database name component of the object qualifier must be the name of the current database.

also tried:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("{call sp_name(?)}");
query.executeUpdate();
query.getParameterValue(1);
```

it didn't work

My Working solution is:

```
Query  query = entityManager.createNativeQuery( "declare @param1 varchar(10) ; exec [otherDb].[dbo].[sp_name] @param1 output; select @param1");     
(String)query.getSingleResult();
```

if you have better solution, please add it here.